# How to tell Backpack for Laravel not to constrain pivot entries to unique pairs in a CRUD form Relationship field type

Tags: duplicates, many-to-many, crud, laravel-backpack

My question is purely about how to tell Backpack not to constrain pivot entries to unique pairs. The rest of my system understands this and works fine outside of the Backpack CRUD controller.

I have a recipe - ingredient many to many relationship with extra pivot columns for quantity, units, and style.

I have stuffed pork recipe that calls for 1 onion (whole) and 1 onion (chopped)

I am using Backpack for Laravel and using a 'relationship' field type on the Recipe crud form to add ingredients and set the quantity, units(oz, g, pints, etc), and style(chopped, grated, etc).

I have a shopping list generator that looks at multiple selected recipes and adds together the repeated items.

Ingredient models should only exist once per shopping style, e.g. for an almond slice you would want your shopping list to have ground almonds and chopped almonds as separate items so theyn exist as separate Ingredient models, but you would not want separate items for whole onions and chopped onions. There would only be one Onion Ingredient model and you would want to see Onions: 2 in your shopping list.

This all works fine except for a recipe like above where it requires the same ingredient twice but in alternative usage styles.

My pivot table has a simple auto-increment primary key and the foreign keys are not a unique pair so I can directly add the same ingredient more than once to offer multiple styles to my table in MySQL if I want, but Backpack does not understand this. It seems to assume each related item must be unique and imposes a foreign key pair constraint that does not exist.

If I add a second item in the crud form Backpack will overwrite the second version of the same ingredient onto the first, or if deleting a second one that was manually added through MySQL client it will fail to delete either unless I ask it to delete both.

Is there an option on the crud relationship definition to set the pivot identifier or how do I override this behaviour?

Tables with just the relevant columns:

```
recipes
    id (pk)
    name (string)

ingredients
    id (pk)
    name (string)

ingredient_recipe
    id (pk)
    ingredient_id (fk)
    recipe_id (fk)
    quantity (decimal)
    units (string, nullable)
    style (string, nullable)
```

Sample data

```
recipes
    id  | name
    1   | Stuffed Pork

ingredients
    id  | name
    1   | Onion
    2   | Pork

ingredient_recipe
    id  | ingredient_id | recipe_id | quantity | units | style
    1   | 2             | 1         | 500      | g     |
    2   | 1             | 1         | 1        |       | whole
    3   | 1             | 1         | 1        |       | finely chopped
```

As you can see, the only thing that makes ingredients 2 and 3 unique is the style.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed information on the issue. I will look into it and hopefully get back to you with some direction.